# Find points making up a triangle from a straight line

Tags: trigonometry

What the formula for finding two points $D$ and $E$ in a two dimensional space, given $A$ and $B$ and the the fact that the angles shown in the figure are 90°.

[image: Problem]

Comment: is it a perfect circle ?

Comment: Are you asking for coordinates, or a geometric construction?

Comment: It is clear that you are missing at least one additional condition.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee , yeah is a perfect circle, Robert i'm asking for coordinates (x,y) for D and E, Moti can you tell what i'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, A is N units under B, and D and E are the same N units to B's right and left, respectively.

So if B is at (X,Y), and A is at (X,Z), then D would be at (X+(Y-Z),Y) and E would be at (X-(Y-Z),Y).